# Match "n" or more words

Tags: vimscript, regular-expression

I want to check if a string consists of n or more words.

I use the following regex to check for 3 words, but the match returns true?

```
:echo '  hello world  ' =~ '^\(\s\{-}\w\+\)\{-3,}'
```

How to make regex matching "n" or more words?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if it's correct, but to check if a string contains 3 words or more I would type this :

```
:echo 'some random string' =~ '\v\s*(\w+\s+){2,}\w+\s*'
```

For 4 words or more :

```
:echo 'some random string' =~ '\v\s*(\w+\s+){3,}\w+\s*'
```

etc.

Edit: [Peter Rincker](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/5376/match-n-or-more-words#comment8247_5378)'s answer seems much better and shorter :

```
\v(\w+(\s+|$)){3,}
```

Not sure but I suppose it can be read as :
*very magic mode enabled (`\v`), a word (`\w+`) followed by either a whitespace (`\s+`) or (`|`) the end of the string (`$`), everything being repeated 3 or more times (`{3,}`)*.

Comment: Shorter regex: `\v(\w+(\s+|$)){3,}`